# Job fails with error : Failed to add row to output buffer SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a data flow task with 2 components :

- source ODBC : with more than 3 000 000 rows
- OLEDB Destination : it's my table destination .

The job works perfectly every day at 2:00 AM .

But this day it fails with the folowing error  message :

> The system reports 97 percent memory. There are 8589463552 bytes of physical memory and 195,731,456 bytes free. There are 2147352576 bytes of virtual memory and 118149120 bytes free. The swap file is 17072041984 bytes and 2497855488 free bytes. A buffer failed while allocating 10485608 bytes. Failed to add row to output buffer.

Note that : this is my server configuration of my customer : 8 G RAM / Processor : 2,6 GHZ

I think it will be a problem of size : so what is the solutions offered for this situation (any tips to configure in SSIS or other) ?

Comment: Sounds like there is competition for free memory on the server. If it's worked every day just fine, it's likely a transient situation and rerunning the package will succeed. If you need to fiddle with knobs to reduce the throughput of your package (recognizing this will increase the total time it takes to run), you'll need to play with the ... buffer settings on the data flow task itself (control flow, right click and pick properties. Can't recall if it's rows & an absolute size or size is computed from row width)